# Get URL inside DIV tag with BS4 Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the next DIV tag

```
<div id="myPano" class="pano" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://www.stax.shop/pub/media/catalog/product/4/5/45c1383853439896cdaf594c318aab7d96c8fb502f22b3be0dc6e35c9e976ee4_7.jpg&quot;); background-position: 3676px center; background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
        <div id="myPanoCycle" class="cycle" style="background:url(https://www.stax.shop/pub/media/catalog/product/4/5/45c1383853439896cdaf594c318aab7d96c8fb502f22b3be0dc6e35c9e976ee4_7.jpg);height:900px;cursor: grab;visibility:hidden;"></div>
    </div>
```

I want to get this url

```
https://www.stax.shop/pub/media/catalog/product/4/5/45c1383853439896cdaf594c318aab7d96c8fb502f22b3be0dc6e35c9e976ee4_7.jpg
```

Its inside style, I dont know how to get it

Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question with your attempt in the form of a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression, but if all `style=` attributes are the same, `str.split` might be enough:

```
print(soup.select_one("#myPanoCycle")["style"].split(")")[0].split("(")[-1])
```

Prints:

```html
https://www.stax.shop/pub/media/catalog/product/4/5/45c1383853439896cdaf594c318aab7d96c8fb502f22b3be0dc6e35c9e976ee4_7.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps.  I would extract the complete "style" value first, and then extract the URL from that using a regular expression.  I think this is easier to understand than doing it all on one line, and it makes it easier to change the logic to address small differences in the format of the HTML:

```
style = soup.select_one("#myPanoCycle")["style"]
url = re.search(r'url\((.*)\)', style).group(1)
print(url)
```

Result:

> https://www.stax.shop/pub/media/catalog/product/4/5/45c1383853439896cdaf594c318aab7d96c8fb502f22b3be0dc6e35c9e976ee4_7.jpg